# Expression to use for somebody very lucky

Tags: phrase-request

In Italian, to mean that somebody is very lucky, we say *nato con la camicia* (literally, "born with the shirt").

Is there an expression I could use in English that is more *colorful* than *very lucky*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of expressions for someone who seems to have all the luck; for example, we might say he has ***all the luck***. A perpetually fortunate person might also

- lead a ***charmed life*** or *blessed life*. She lives as if under a magic spell that grants only good luck, or is looked with favor upon by God.
- have been ***born under a lucky star***, or other astrological phenomena.
- be a *lucky dog* or *lucky duck*, informally. This expression is used both to say someone has enjoyed a recent string of good luck, and to say s/he lives with good luck in general. To tease enviously, one might say he's a *lucky stiff*, or in British English, a *jammy bastard*.
- *have nine lives.* Such a person has escape perilous, perhaps deadly situations on many occasions.

Comment: Also, similar but a bit more old fashioned is *born under the dog star*, which means roughly the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

There is a phrase:

[***born under a lucky star***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/born+under+a+lucky+star)

and also
[***born with a silver spoon in his mouth***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_spoon) although this connotes more of being born wealthy (which is a pretty lucky thing to have happened) than just being straight lucky.

Comment: But as the Emerson, Lake & Palmer track [Lucky Man](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/emerson+lake+palmer/lucky+man_20049799.html) makes clear, just because you're "born with a silver spoon in your mouth" doesn't mean you'll continue to be lucky.

Comment: Yeah, war is rarely lucky for anyone.

Comment: I sometimes say, "That guy's a regular Mr. Magoo." but I'm pretty sure that's not a standard idiom.

Comment: I know it's "only a movie", but in practical terms I think [Thirteen Days](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0146309/) is accurate insofar as it basically shows most of the US military top brass and big industrialists as spoiling for a fight. ["War is good for business"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22war+is+good+for+business%22&oq=%22war+is+good+for+business%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.10324&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), as they say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Actually, the ELP lyrics continue to assert the man was lucky, even after his noble death.

Comment: @J.R.: Ah, but I think you'd have to agree that the final chorus after *A bullet had found him \ His blood ran as he cried \ No money could save him \ So he laid down and he died* is definitely "ironic". Most of us could do without that kind of "luck". (actually, I always hear it as *so he **lay** down and he died*, but that's pedantry for you! :)

Comment: @Fumble: I didn't want to engage in a debate on this, but, since you've quoted the words I already knew, I'll elaborate. I remember hearing this song on the radio while riding with my dad in a car, years and years ago, and I asked him what was "lucky" about death in battle. I can't remember his exact answer, but it was along the lines of how history might remember the man for his bravery and unselfish courage, perhaps he'd achieve some kind of renown from his untimely but heroic death, and how that could be considered a form of luck, too. Since ELP explicitly call him lucky, I'll go with that.

Comment: P.S. You might find it "ironic," but, after hearing my dad's explanation, I've always regarded it as more "poetic" than "ironic."

Comment: @J.R.: I'm sure StoneyB would be happy to read your comments there, regardless of whether *he* thinks our hero is still "lucky" at his end. He firmly believes that *reading* is a creative activity where the reader creates much of the meaning for himself. Listening to lyrics must fall more into that category than, say, watching movies (witness ['Scuse me, while I kiss this guy](http://www.kissthisguy.com/18-jimi-hendrix-purple-haze-misheard-lyrics.htm) :)

Comment: @Fumble: That's one way to shrug off my dad's interpretation. :^) I suppose I'm biased, because I've always regarded my father as a man of much wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

In British English, there's a great term for this:

> He came off his motorcycle going at 70mph and walked away? That's awfully **jammy**
>
> Dave won the lottery? That **jammy** sod.

(In this case the offensiveness of the term "sod" is offset by the term "jammy", but be careful when using it).

The phrase **jammy** in this context comes from a brand of biscuits in the UK called *Jammy Dodgers*, hence someone who is able to dodge bad events or is very lucky can be referred to as **jammy**. Generally the word *jammy* is applied as an adjective to an offensive noun, such as *jammy bastard*, *jammy sod* etc, but a less offensive (and less common) form is to use the original:

> You woke up two hours late for your interview, caught the wrong bus, and were *still* there before the interviewer? You **jammy dodger**.